# Overlay Not Showing in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm showing and hidding a div using its visibility in css. It works fine in every other browse except IE8 & 9 and I can quite figure out why. From looking at this, can anyone possibly give an answer?

HTML

```
<div id="action-panel">
            Show mne
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#action-panel {
    position : fixed;
    height: 80%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    right: 10px;
    visibility:hidden;
    display: block;
    top: 10%;
    overflow:scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: groove;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And the javascript

```
$('#action-panel').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Seems like it should work unless I am missing something back

Comment: If you remove the line with visibility: hidden from your css, and remove your javascript, is it showing then?

Comment: Yes it does, it shows the div with the text

Comment: This does not solve your problem right? I've tested your code on ie8 on Win XP, works for me. Maybe the context is different? Play around with the parent height.

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is executed (without exceptions)?